# In Multi-NSF Application, How to Clear Session?

Tags: xpages

When the user clicks a logout link, it's easy to clear the current database's sessionScope map:

```
var iterator=sessionScope.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  sessionScope.remove(iterator.next());
}
```

But this only clears the sessionScope variables for the current NSF, not for all NSFs on the server. So if they then log in as a different user and navigate to other NSFs that they have previously accessed during that browser session, the browser session still picks up the sessionScoped variables for the previously logged on user.

If the application spans multiple NSFs, how do you clear the browser's session from all NSFs on the server?

**UPDATE**

After discussions, I got a hold of the session from facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getSession(false) and then called the invalidate() method on it. That didn't work, it still has the same session ID and the scoped variables are retained. I think Declan's idea of the cookie is the cause. I believe that is used by the Notes Client quite heavily too.

Comment: After clearing the sessionscope are you redirecting the user to a url with ?logout appended ?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that. Scoped variables though are managed by the XSP Command Manager, not the Domino HTTP server which is logged out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a session cookie called 'sessionID' on the browser side.

What happens if you invalidate/clear that cookie during the logout process?

Comment: That's the key. I've added the code to XSnippets on OpenNTF.
http://openntf.org/s/clear-session-whole-server

To log out as well, the code is this in CSJS:
    
    document.cookie="SessionID=; path=/";
    location.href="./?logout"</code>

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to clear the sessionScope of another database, but you might consider a different approach: store the name of the user that initialized the sessionScope in the sessionScope and compare that with the name of the user trying to initialize it. If the names are different, clear the sessionScope and initialize it again.

Comment: I think this is the best option you have.